# Oracle query optimization hints

Tags: sql, database, oracle, optimization

What is the most preferable way and proformancive way of Oracle sql query.

1. Using Join in query
2. Query without using JOIN

What is the impact on Oracle database when using above senarios?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Are you talking about the difference between the old style join syntax `from a, b where a.b_id = b.b_id` rather than the SQL 99 join syntax `from a join b on (a.b_id = b.b_id)`?  Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I am asking about the difference between the old style join syntax `FROM a, b WHERE a.b_id = b.b_id ` rather than the SQL 99 join syntax `FROM a join b ON a.b_id = b.b_id`. Which method is most prefferable and have more performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JOIN syntax is preferred from a style point of view. It makes your query much easier to read and easier to debug join issues. Especially on queries with many joins and filtering conditions.

From a performance perspective there is no difference. The database is going to do the exact same thing as long as the join conditions are the same.